# jQuery Photo Search Results Pagination using AJAX and JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, pagination, photo

I have a "photo search" page that needs to present search results in a 5x5 grid of photo thumbnails. I'd like to populate this grid using the JSON results of a jQuery `$.ajax()` call to my ASP.NET web service. Where I'm struggling is with pagination, where clicking `[First][Prev][1][2][3]...[20][21][Next][Last]` will call back again via ajax and repopulate the results with the appropriate images. So I need to find a solution to both the pagination control itself and the search results. Is there a jQuery plugin for this, or something I can easily adapt for my purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this question, I solved my problem using the jQuery Pagination plugin: http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm

This demo can be easily adapted to get the array of JSON photo objects (or any object type for that matter) using an AJAX call on page load. Subsequent paging operations do not call back to the server with this plugin, so you may want to limit your search results to say 1000 records or so.